# pandas crosstab simplified view of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I already referred the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148069/crosstab-on-multiple-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544448/python3-pandas-crosstab-for-two-columns). Don't mark it as duplicate

I have a dataframe like as below

```
id,status,country,amount,qty
1,pass,USA,123,4500
1,pass,USA,156,3210
1,fail,UK,687,2137
1,fail,UK,456,1236
2,pass,AUS,216,324
2,pass,AUS,678,241
2,nan,ANZ,637,213
2,pass,ANZ,213,543

sf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to get the percentage of values from each column as a seperate column

So, with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72372825/pandas-groupby-and-compute-ratio-of-values-with-na-in-multiple-columns), I tried the below

**Approach - 1  Doesn't give expected output shape**

```
(pd.crosstab(sf['id'],[sf['status'].fillna('nan'),sf['country'].fillna('nan')],normalize=0)
          .drop('nan', 1)
          .mul(100)).reset_index()
```

**Approach - 2 - Doesn't give expected output**

```
sf_inv= sf.melt()
pd.crosstab(sf_inv.value, sf_inv.variable)
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Comment: shouldn't pass_pct/2 be 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize='index'` on your different columns and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the results:

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(sf['id'], sf[c], normalize='index')
           for c in ['status', 'country']], axis=1).mul(100).add_suffix('_pct')
```

output:

```
    fail_pct  pass_pct  ANZ_pct  AUS_pct  UK_pct  USA_pct
id                                                       
1       50.0      50.0      0.0      0.0    50.0     50.0
2        0.0     100.0     50.0     50.0     0.0      0.0
```

###### handling NaNs:

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(sf['id'], sf[c].fillna('NA'), normalize='index')
             .drop(columns='NA', errors='ignore')
           for c in ['status', 'country']], axis=1).mul(100).add_suffix('_pct')
```

output:

```
    fail_pct  pass_pct  ANZ_pct  AUS_pct  UK_pct  USA_pct
id                                                       
1       50.0      50.0      0.0      0.0    50.0     50.0
2        0.0      75.0     50.0     50.0     0.0      0.0
```

Comment: `pass_pct` for id=2 will be 75% because of `NA`. We should not count `NA`..

Comment: which NA? Can you pinpoint it?

Comment: @TheGreat - try your solution, more complicated like seems ;)

Comment: @mozway - apologies, missed the nan earlier. updated the input datframe